# Infinite Loop for finding a power set for a string

Tags: javascript, string, subset

I'm working on a problem where I need to find all the power set of a given string which are all the possible subsets. I feel like I'm close with my current code but I can't figure out why I'm getting stuck on an infinite loop for my second iteration. I ran it through the debugger but I still can't seem to figure it out even though I'm sure it's very simple. When `i = 0` then it goes to the second loop where `j = 0 && j < 1` so for example if `help` is my given str argument then I would expect it to add `j + ''` and push it into my `allSubsets` array. The problem is that the `j` iteration will keep looping and doing `j++` and will never stop. I'm not sure why this is. One particular question even if I solve this infinite loop - do I need to update the `allSubsets.length` in the iteration to keep it updated with the pushed in strings?

```
var powerSet = function(str) {

   let allSubsets = [''];

   for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    debugger;
        for (let j = 0; j < allSubsets.length; j++) {
            allSubsets.push(sortLetters(str[i] + allSubsets[j]));
        }
   }
   return allSubsets;
};

var sortLetters = (word => {
    //convert string to an array
    //use the sort to sort by letter
    //convert array back to string and return
    return word.split('').sort().join('');
})
```

Comment: Side note: since you need to end up with (2^length) elements it is extremely unlikely that basic nested loop (usually length^2, also it is very unclear what you expect from your code) would not be enough.

Comment: In the 2nd for loop, you're updating the `allSubsets` array for every iteration so the loop will never stop and the same element will be pushed to the `allSubsets` array infinite times. check you can change on which the 2nd loop can be iterated

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, I'm new to this but how do you know its 2^length elements? What I'm expecting is this. For example, if the string argument is `jump` then `allSubsets =[
  '',     'j',   'u',
  'ju',   'm',   'jm',
  'mu',   'jmu', 'p',
  'jp',   'pu',  'jpu',
  'mp',   'jmp', 'mpu',
  'jmpu'
]`

Comment: Each element either includes given letter (1) or skips (0), so you get - 0000 (""), 0001 ("p"), 0010 ("m"), 0011 ("mp"),... 1111 ("jump") - which is *exactly 2^4. You are trying to generate them in different order, which is fine but the total number of elements in a set does not change because of reordering.

Comment: @upender thanks! I don't know how I totally missed that - it make sense it'll be an infinite loop. I fixed the length to be calculated at the start of each iteration of the first loop and it works

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you push to `allSubSets`, the length increases, and thus, your loop never ends. A declarative loop runs on the range of the initial loop. See below for a fix based on your code:

```js
var powerSet = function(str) {

   let allSubsets = [''];

   for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        allSubsets.forEach( (_char, j) => { // declarative loop here
            allSubsets.push(sortLetters(str[i] + allSubsets[j]));
        })
   }
   return allSubsets;
};

var sortLetters = (word => {
    return word.split('').sort().join('');
})
```

From MDN web docs:

> The range of elements processed by forEach() is set before the first invocation of callback. Elements which are appended to the array after the call to forEach() begins will not be visited by callback. If existing elements of the array are changed or deleted, their value as passed to callback will be the value at the time forEach() visits them; elements that are deleted before being visited are not visited. If elements that are already visited are removed (e.g. using shift()) during the iteration, later elements will be skipped. (See this example, below.)

See the fourth paragraph under descriptions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description